# TCPHandler not callable

Tags: python, tcp

I use a TCPServer in Python to send and receive data, i have create my class TCPHandler with a constructor like this :

```py
class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, parameter):
        super()
        ...
    def handle(self):
        ...
```

And I have this error :

```
TypeError: 'MyTCPHandler' object is not callable
```

Did somenone hava any about why I get this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke `super().__init__()` instead of just `super()` in `MyTCPHandler.__init__` method.